Question about action of exponential of Lie algebras (Faraut and Koranyi's book).
I'm trying to understand a statement on page 49 in the book "Analysis on Symmetric Cones" by Faraut and Koranyi.
The situation is as follows. Let $\Omega$ be a symmetric cone in $V$ and denote by $G$ the connected component of the identity in $G(Ω)$ (the automorphisms of the cone $\Omega$). Now consider $K := G \cap O(V)$ where $O(V) := \{T \in \mathrm{GL(V)} \colon T^* = T^{-1}\}$. There is an element $e \in \Omega$ such that $K$ equals the stabilizer subgroup $G_e$ of $G$. For $G$ and $K$ we have the corresponding Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ of $K$, respectively. It turns out that $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p} := \{T \in \mathfrak{g} \colon T^* = T\}$. Since $\Omega$ is symmetric, $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$, that is $G \cdot e = \Omega$. Furthermore, as $\mathfrak{k} \cdot e = 0$, we have $\mathfrak{g}\cdot e = \mathfrak{p}\cdot e$.
Could someone please help me understand why this implies $\exp \mathfrak{g} \cdot e = \exp \mathfrak{p} \cdot e$? If possible using the least amount of Lie theory. I'm not an expert in the theory of Lie groups or Lie algebras.

Do you mean $\mathfrak{p}$ in the last part there? $\exp \mathfrak{k} \cdot e = {e}$ so certainly isn't equal to $\exp \mathfrak{g} \cdot e$.

Yes, that was a typo, apologies. I changed it.

Firstly we note that for $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ we have $$\exp(X)\cdot e = e + X\cdot e + \frac{1}{2}X\cdot(X\cdot e) + \cdots.$$
If $\mathfrak{g}\cdot e = \mathfrak{p}\cdot e$ then we are saying for any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ we have $X\cdot e = Y\cdot e$ for some $Y\in \mathfrak{p}$. It immediately follows that $\exp(X)\cdot e = \exp(Y) \cdot e$ and thus $\exp\mathfrak{g}\cdot e = \exp\mathfrak{p}\cdot e$

Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why $X \cdot e=Y \cdot e$ would imply that $X^n⋅e = Y^n⋅e$?

@MarkRoelands you are correct sorry. Thinking about it further, I am not convinced it is necessarily true unless we assume $\exp\mathfrak{p}\cdot e$ means up to repeated applications and in that case proving it seems a little more involved.
